# Decomposition of a Lie subalgebra of $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{K})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ and let $L\subset\text{Mat}(n,\mathbb{K})$ be a Lie subalgebra with $M\in L\Rightarrow M^\ast\in L$, where $M^\ast$ is the transpose ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$) or the hermitian conjugate ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$).

I know:

1. $(\cdot,\cdot):L\times L\rightarrow\mathbb{C},~(M,N)\mapsto\text{tr}(M^\ast N)$ is a positive definite inner product on $L$.
2. For a subset $S\subset L$ define $$S':=\{x\in L|(x,s)=0~\forall s\in S\}.$$ We have $I$ ideal $\Rightarrow I'$ ideal.

I want to know why we have $L=I\oplus I'$ for an ideal $I\subset L$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305967/l-subset-textmatn-mathbbk-lie-subalgebra-with-m-in-l-rightarrow-m-ast) by user372565.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Lie algebras. Your statement (that is, $L=I\oplus I'$) holds for any positive definite inner product on any finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this info, but a reason would be great :)

Comment: Let $P\colon L\longrightarrow I$ be the orthogonal projection from $L$ onto $I$. Then, for each $X\in L$, $X=P(X)+\bigl(X-P(X)\bigr)$. Besides, $P(X)\in I$ and $X-P(X)\in I'$. This proves that $L=I+I'$. On the other hand, if $X\in I\cap I'$, then $(X,X)=0$. Therefore, $L=I\oplus I'$.

Comment: How does the orthogonal projection looks like here? I.e. what does the function?

Comment: The orthogonal prejection $P$ is the function from $L$ to $I$ such that, for each $X\in L$, $P(X)$ is the element of $I$ closest to $X$. The distance here is the one induced by the norm $\|X\|=\sqrt{(X,X)}$. It turns out that $P$ is a linear map and that $P\circ P=P$.

Comment: Is there ne explizit form $P(X)=...$ which makes is easier to calculate with?

Comment: Sure. If $(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_k)$ is an orthonormal basis of $I$ and if $X\in L$, define $P(X)$ as $(X,e_1)e_1+(X,e_2)e_2+\cdots+(X,e_k)e_k$.